# Prometheus config not shoing in Prometheus GUI

Tags: prometheus, open-telemetry

I have added a new configuration in the ConfigMap of Prometheus. Below is the config that I have added.

```
  - job_name: 'OpenTelemetryTest'
    scrape_interval: 1s # poll very quickly for a more responsive demo
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9184']
```

But the configuration is not reflected in the Prometheus GUI. It doesn't show the above added config in GUI.

I refreshed the config using the below. But the configuration is not showing in Prometheus GUI

```
curl -X POST https://prom-xxxxx.com/-/reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the configuration was reloaded? This endpoint is disabled by default and must be enabled via the --web.enable-lifecycle flag.

See more info at Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/management_api/#reload)